# removing ^m characters within a script within a container using dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

When we clone that repo, and run the build, there are ^m charecters in a script inside a container. I am using dockerfile to install 'dos2unix' to remove them but it does not work. s.

dockerfile:

```
FROM raj/oracle19c:new

  
RUN yum install -y dos2unix vim
   
COPY ./post_setup/ /opt/oracle/scripts/setup/

RUN find /opt/oracle/scripts/startup/ -type f -name "*.sh" -exec bash -c 'dos2unix "$0" && chmod +x "$0"' {} \;
```

docker build log:

```
> => transferring context: 1.71MB                                                                                                                                                                             0.1s 
 => [db 2/6] RUN yum install -y dos2unix vim                                                                                                                                                                   28.3s 
                                                                                                                                                  0.0s 
 => [db 5/6] COPY ./post_setup/ /opt/oracle/scripts/setup/                                                                                                                                                      0.0s 
 => [db 6/6] RUN find /opt/oracle/scripts/startup/ -type f -name "*.sh" -exec bash -c 'dos2unix "$0" && chmod +x "$0"' {} ;                                                                                     0.2s 
 => [db] exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                                     2.3s 
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                                         2.3s 
 => => writing image sha256:d5d033e73a1f5af57292513d0004a01a1a6643e3240ddda4a074ed19a9622c02                                                                                                                    0.0s 
 => => naming to docker.io/raj/oracle19c:new
```

When i logon to the container and type `cat -A filename` i can see the ^M characters.

Any advice in how best to remove them?

Comment: yes it does so thanks for that